# Multiple "ObjectChangeTracker" getting created, can it be avoided?

Tags: wpf, wcf, entity-framework-4

We are working on a POC where we have following architecture (MVVM),

WPF(Client) + WCF + Model(DataAccess)+ ADO.Net Entity Framework 4.0 (with SQL Server 2008 R2 as DB)

All are different projects.

In the DataAccess layer we have created different Entity Models(edmx) based on the functionality. The tables under perticular flow are grouped and created different entity models. We are using self tracking entities to and fro to communicate with the WPF client through wcf service. For Single model everything works fine. But when we created a Multiple models then few issues started coming. Mutliple models have few duplicate tables/entities. Two probels are,

1) When we try to access entities from different models mutiple objects "ObjectChangeTracker" are getting created.
 E.g.
  CompanyModel(edmx) - Company(Entity) - ObjectChangeTracker, ObjectState
  ProductModel(edmx) - Customer(Entity) - ObjectChangeTracker1, ObjectState1
  OrderModel(edmx) - Oder(Entity) - ObjectChangeTracker2, ObjectState2

Is there any way to avoid this?

2) There are few tables which shared across the Models, E.g. Company(Entity) is used in All above mdoels. During compile time it does not thow any error. But run time It gives error saying "Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type "Company"".. To resolve this, we renamed the entities with some prefix to make them Unique. Is there any other way we can resolve this without changing the name of the entity in the same assembly?

Thanks in advance and appreciate if anyone has approach for these issues.

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you enabling the ChangeTracker always when you grab entities from your data access?
I guess you can't avoid what is created unless you use the POCO Template. It has some more job to be done in some matters but you will have lighter objects. You must then manage the entity state by yourself. I think its good to stay on selftracking but while you use WCF you should change the collection type to FixUpCollection as i can remember to work better with your WCF Service. HINT: Don't forget to disable lazy loading or else you will end up having all the child records you night not want when the entities are serialized.

2) Try and seperate the models in different assemblies, is a better practice and i think you will overcome these problems. I worked this way and its ok.

Hope i helped....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We could resolve the first issue by creating separate service class for each model. By doing this, separate "ObjectChangeTracker" is created for every models. We need to add those many service references in WPF client I am not sure how much this is correct. For second issue, right now we have 4 models , we may end up having more than 20 mdoels so do you think creating those many assemblies will be the right approach?. Thanks, Kiran

Comment: Change the models namespaces, every model different namespace, this could solve your problem. It's a thought. This way i guess you could resolve separated service class which is bad design as you say.